# How to copy across terminals using text editor vim without clipboard support?

Tags: linux, terminal, vim

options in my version of vim :

```
vim --version | grep clip
-clipboard         +jumplist          +popupwin          +user_commands
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
```

I can copy from file A and paste into file B if I stay within the same instance of vim by using **:e path-to-B** command to edit B , but I don't know how to do it if I want to edit file A in one terminal and file B in another one . I got a few answers from the web but I found them a bit complicated . I could use g.vim to have the clipboard option enabled but I prefer to stick with vim.basic .

It seems to me that registers in terminal A cannot be read from terminal B , so there is nothing to paste into file B . That's as far as I can go to explain it but I don't see how I can solve this problem .

Comment: I tried xclip and I could copy a selected line in xclip then export it in file B . So it's almost solved but there is still a glitch : copying in xclip with :'<,'>w !xclip copies a whole line where the selection I want to paste stands . Of course I can trim the line in file B but if I could avoid it that would be great . Is it possible to replace the command :'<,'>w !xclip by something more appropriate ?

Comment: problem solved using :call system('xclip', @0)